# Virtual File System using scala or java

Tags: akka, hdfs, apache-commons-vfs, javers

I'm working on the project where I need to store files in HDFS or S3 buckets. 
Problem is that I need to store each file with unique GUID. The application need keep track of the versions of the file and return the latest versions.

I'm looking at [Apache Commons VFS](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) and  [Javers](http://javers.org/). 
Both are offering something closer to what I need. Problem is that commons doesn't have hdfs write and versioning. Javers is object versions and diffs. 
Is there anyone who used any of these libraries for similar purpose?
Any pros or cons? Any insight of these two libraries or any other existing library's reference which would solve my problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JaVers is designed for versioning domain objects, not for files. So I'm afraid it won't help you unless you map those files to some more structured (java) objects.